# Is there a readily available liquid within which one could successfully fully submerge and run a PC?

Tags: cooling

Liquid cooling taken to the extreme? No fans, just all the hardware submerged in Liquid X?

Q1: Can this be done?

Q2: Can this be done outside of DARPA? (i.e., with a substance readily available to regular folks)

Q3: Are there any successful examples out there?

For science!

Comment: I hate to be snarky, but it's 09:02 here and I haven't had my first coffee yet, - have you tried a Web search as there's tons of sites covering this.

Comment: my web access is filtered with a whitelist :-/

Comment: I agree with Linker somewhat that I would advise you to ask for an explanation of how its possible and what you should look out for when doing something like this. Simply proving that it can be done isn't all that interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its all been done before.  Mineral oil, vegetable oil, basically any non conductive liquid.

Check [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtufuXLvOok) for an example of a pc in mineral oil.

FYI, it doesnt reduce heat as much as you think.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot's of examples of DIY ones that run in mineral oil out there. Here's a link to a [site](http://www.pugetsystems.com/submerged.php) that will supply the components.